# S3 Multipart Upload using NiFi

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am ingesting large volume of data from a relational database into AWS S3.  Since the volume is large, I am breaking it down by multiple SQL pull, create smaller flowfiles, then merge and then upload to AWS S3. Is there a way to upload these file chunks to AWS S3 and then do a final merge after all the uploads for that particular table is complete?

The [PutS3Object](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object/index.html) processor i am using has a multipart upload option, but it appears to me this method first expect the large file to be created locally first and then the upload loads in chunks. Is my understanding correct? I am trying to avoid that step of merging smaller flowfiles into one before uploading.

Answer (score 0):

PutS3Object processor uses either putObject method or multipart upload method to upload files to AWS S3. Behind the scenes both of these methods are available as part of AWS SDK for Java.

Amazon S3 offers the following options:

- Upload objects in a single operation—With a single PUT operation, you
  can upload objects up to 5 GB in size.
- Upload objects in parts—Using
  the multipart upload API, you can upload large objects, up to 5 TB.

In PutS3Object processor multipart upload kicks in only when the file size is larger than threshold size set using '**Multipart Threshold**' attribute.
If the file size is less than threshold size then there is no chance for multipart upload.

> Is there a way to upload these file chunks to AWS S3 and then do a final merge after all the uploads for that particular table is complete?

There could be ways but not using PutS3Object processor. In fact, AWS S3 multipart upload API works like this when used - split larger file, upload in chunks and merge at the end.

> I am breaking it down by multiple SQL pull, create smaller flowfiles, then merge and then upload to AWS S3

One possible way is to create a larger flow file with entire relational database data, if possible, instead of creating smaller flow files and Let the PutS3Object processor handle file upload.

Multipart upload consists of three steps initiate upload, upload the parts, and complete the upload. This process saves state, locally tracking the upload ID and parts uploaded, after each step so that a large upload can be resumed with minimal loss if the processor or cluster is stopped and restarted.

Hope this answer solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you split records and append a variable at the end indicating what # file it is in the split. Then uploading all to s3 sequentially.